# How do I access the target's associated functions when using `Deref`?

Tags: rust

I need to implement the `fmt::Display` method for an object coming from an external crate, so I created a wrapper for this object. I'd like to be able to use all the methods from the original object, without having to redefine all of them. I tried to implement `Deref` as advised on the awesome IRC channel `#rust-beginners`:

```
struct CustomMap(ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>);

impl std::ops::Deref for CustomMap {
    type Target = ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cm = CustomMap::with_capacity(10);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

However, I'm getting this error :

```
error: no associated item named `with_capacity` found for type `CustomMap` in the current scope
  --> <anon>:16:13
   |
16 |     let a = CustomMap::with_capacity(10);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume it's because `deref()` doesn't work with associated functions.

How can I work around this? Reimplementing every associated function I use, just to be able to implement one method I need seems like overkill.

Comment: I've updated your question because the tuple struct is a red-herring here. Regardless of the type of struct, you'll run into the same type of problem. Sadly, I'm pretty sure that the answer is "you can't".

Comment: `Display` is generally reserved for `String` conversion, if the type implements `Debug` (and it should, in general), you can display it with `println!("{:?}", value)`. As such, I have two questions: (1) do you really need `Display`? and, if it is, (2) would implementing a proxy (over a reference to this type) and only constructing the proxy when `Display` is needed suitable for your problem?

Comment: @MatthieuM. nice thinking outside of the box! A `println!("{}", DisplayMap(&my_map))` would be pretty *and* idiomatic.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I've used the proxy scheme in C++ enough that it's second nature... but it won't help if the OP needs to use this type in generic with `T: Display` bound :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newtypes are specifically designed to provide encapsulation, so they do not necessarily lend them well to just "adding new stuff".

That being said, a combination of:

- `Deref` and `DerefMut` to get access to the methods
- `From` and `Into` to easily convert from one to the other
- OR making the inner type `pub`

should be able to tackle this.

The `From`/`Into` recommendation comes from the fact that most associated functions are generally constructors<sup>1</sup>.

```
impl From<ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>> for CustomMap { ... }
```

and then you can do:

```
let cm: CustomMap = ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>::with_capacity(10).into();
```

The other solution is to define `CustomMap` as:

```
struct CustomMap(pub ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>);
```

and then:

```
let cm = CustomMap(ObjectComingFromAnExternalCrate<char, char>::with_capacity(10));
```

If you do not wish to enforce any other invariant, and do not care about encapsulation, either should get you going.

<sup>1</sup> *Pointer types, such as `Rc`, use them heavily to avoid hiding methods of the Deref'ed to type.*